# How to scroll horizontally with mouse drag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a task like kanban board. Everything is working fine but when I click on vertical scroll bar it hides and I am not able to scroll up and down.
[image]

I am using below code for horizontally scrolling on drag

```
$('.at-priortyboxsholder').mousedown(function (event) {
        $(this)
            .data('down', true)
            .data('x', event.clientX)
            .data('scrollLeft', this.scrollLeft)
            .addClass("dragging");
            $(this).css('overflow','hidden')

            return false;
          }).mouseup(function (event) {
              $(this)
                .data('down', false)
                .removeClass("dragging");

          }).mousemove(function (event) {
              if ($(this).data('down') == true) {
                  this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollLeft') + $(this).data('x') - event.clientX;
              }
          }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css('overflow','auto')
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by updating code

```
$('.at-priortyboxsholder').mousedown(function (event) {
        $(this)
            .data('down', true)
            .data('x', event.clientX)
            .data('scrollLeft', this.scrollLeft)
            .addClass("dragging");
            
          }).mouseup(function (event) {
              $(this)
                .data('down', false)
                .removeClass("dragging");

          }).mousemove(function (event) {
              if ($(this).data('down') == true) {
                $(this).css('overflow','hidden')
                  this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollLeft') + $(this).data('x') - event.clientX;
              }
          }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css('overflow','auto')
        });
```